# How do I save a file Withou extension in linux?

Tags: linux, file, file-extension

Recently i was trying to save a file as "ssh" for my raspberry pi, with which i'm having trouble configuring. the only way i can save a file without extension is on windows. is there any way i can do that on linux so i won't need to keep changing O.S all the time?

Comment: I guess that depends on the program you are using to create the file. Windows and Linux are Operating Systems, not text editors...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what you're using but unix (and linux by extension (no pun intended)) don't even have the concept of an extension on a filename. It's all just a filename and there can be dots in them. The 8.3 thing came from MS-DOS ...

So to create a file called "ssh" just name it that, no dot no extension and you're done.

E.g.:

```
$ echo "hello world" > ssh
```

or

```
$ vi ssh
```

etc. all are capable of creating a file called ssh (take care with the first one, it'll overwriting existing files).

Also if you have a file salled let's say "ssh.whatever", you can rename it with

```
$ mv ssh.whatever ssh
```

If you have a tool that's not allowing you to create a file without an extension on a unix system, odds are it's not something that was made by somebody who knows what they were doing.